# I can't read the response on a connection to an SMTP server

Tags: javascript, node.js, email

Here is my code:

```
socket = new net.Socket().connect(465, 'smtp.gmail.com', () => {
  console.log('Connected')
  socket.write('HELO smtp.gmail.com\r\n')
}).on('data', (data) => console.log(data))
```

When I run it, I get `<Buffer 15 03 01 00 02 02 46>`, and when converted to text, it's unreadable.
How do I turn this into readable JSON/text/whatever it is?

Comment: What you got back was apparently binary.  It is not readable text.  The bytes `15 03 01 00 02 02` are all non-text.

Comment: Before anyone says: "Use nodemailer!", I know what nodemailer is. I just only want to use the built-in libraries.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'll see what I can do with that information.

Comment: It's unreadable when you try to convert it to text because the buffer does not contain text.  The `15 03 01 00 02 02` part of the buffer is all non-ascii (e.g. binary).

Comment: @jfriend00, should it be converted to binary based on bytes or as a single number?

Comment: One possible guess.  I think SSL is required for `smtp.gmail.com`.  So maybe this is the beginnings of an SSL session. Perhaps you should be establishing an SSL socket first rather than a plain socket.

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00, I have figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer thanks to help from @white11 and @jfriend00:

See https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html for decoding TLS streams.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that you are opening a socket against a TLS server. What you get is binary data, not a plain text string.

If you connect to an endpoint  a responding plain text which is a JSON string, you could use the toJSON() method, such as:

```
console.log(data.toJSON())
```

If data is not a JSON you can simply use the toString() method to get a string:

```
console.log(data.toString());
```

More details about the Buffer class in the official documentation here https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Comment: I know. But try my code yourself. The returned text is unreadable.

Comment: It gives you, "non-existant char, non-existant char, non-existant char, space, non-existant char, non-existant char, F"

Comment: `.toString()` does not convert binary data to a readable string when the binary data does not represent readable characters.

Comment: Since you are connecting to the Gmail SMTP server, I guess that the data stream you are getting is a TLS stream, and that explains why data is unreadable.
You have to use an SMTP client library to connect to that server.

Comment: Yeah correct @jfriend00, I just thought that the binary stream was representing a string, otherwise the original question doesn&#39;t make real sense. By the way, problem here is with the fact that the socket is opened towards a TLS encrypted server (Gmail SMTP)

Comment: @JacobTDC you can try using the TLS module. You can find an example here https://gist.github.com/anhldbk/3ea07d006c0fd411f19c0e362d4e0ec0

Comment: @whites11, I found a built-in module for doing it, and have posted it as an answer. Thank you SOOOO much!